# Formatação com php de numéricos para salvar no banco de dados mysql como DECIMAL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a implementar o Ckeckout Cielo e é retornado sempre valores numéricos para os preços.

Os valores monetários são sempre tratados como valores inteiros, sem representação das casas decimais, sendo que os dois últimos dígitos são considerados como os centavos.

`Exemplo: R$ 1.286,87 é representado como 128687 e  R$ 1,00 é representado como 100`

Penso em usar a função do `substr_replace` para acrescentar `(.)` antes das duas últimas casas, como no exemplo que segue:

`substr_replace(100000, '.', -2,0) = 1000.00`

`substr_replace(100, '.', -2,0) = 1.00`

Neste contexto, aplicar a `substr_replace` para gravação de valores deciamais no banco de dados `Mysql` seria adequado para qualquer valor monetário vindo da cielo?

Comment: dividi por `100` !!!

Comment: tem que averiguar se isso é assim mesmo, como no exemplo `128687` se formatação nenhuma o correto é dividir por `100`, se o número tiver casas decimais o banco irá gravar se não também, mas, o que seria bom é verificar junto a CIELO ou manual se é assim mesmo.

Comment: @Virgilio Novic o primeiro exemplo foi tirado na íntegra do manual da Cielo.

Comment: então, faça a divisão por `100`! o valor já poderia ser inclusive salvo na base!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso da ***CIELO*** relatado, indicaria a divisão por **100** e abandonaria a ***idéia*** de utilizar `substr_replace`, porque:

Valores abaixo de **100**, no caso **20** poderia trazer um dado assim:

***Código***

```
echo substr_replace(20, '.', -2,0);
//saída .20
```

ou ***pior*** ainda valores com uma casa:

```
echo substr_replace(2, '.', -2,0);
//saída .2 no qual o correto deveria ser 0.02
```

Com a divisão do valor por `100` o valor seria *formatado* e *adequado* para gravação no banco:

```
echo 20 / 100;
//saída 0.2
echo 2 / 100;
//saída 0.02
echo 128687 / 100;
//saída 1286.87
```

Pelo que pude percebe a divisão resolve seu problema.

Comment: Gostei da solução, porém no caso CIELO não retorna valores de uma casa só. 1,00 retorna 100 e 20,00 retorna 2000. Vou usar a divisão, obrigado.