# Formatar casas decimais em PHP usando ponto e virgula

Tags: php, aplicação-web, decimal

Tenho um modulo de pagamento onde eu devo passar os dados sem casas decimais, somente número. Exemplos:

> `10,00` = `1000`
>
> `100,30` = `10030`
>
> `1.000,00` = `100000`

Pesquisei sobre alguma função em `php` que ***formate casas decimais***, mas os teste que realizei não saíram como o esperado, alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa questão?

Comment: Dá uma [olhada aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: relacionada: [Formatação com php de numéricos para salvar no banco de dados mysql como DECIMAL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159594/54880)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso, o que você precisa é muito simples, remover qualquer valor que não seja número:

```
$entrada = '100,30'; 

echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$entrada);
```

[**Exemplo no IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/c4QBG3)

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, mas eu acho que a pergunta ficou confusa, no caso seria o contrario eu tenho o valor sem ponto e virgula e quero formatar usando casas decimais.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) colocando o que busca em um [`array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) e o que muda no caso particular ***aspas sem espaço*** (`''`):

```
<?php

$numero = "1.000,00";
$result = str_replace(['.',','],'', $numero);
echo $result;
```

[***Exemplo Online Ideone***](http://ideone.com/5JlHPL)

*Referencia:*

- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

---

***Edit:***

*Realmente* [já existe um resposta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159594/54880)

Comment: uncionou perfeitamente, mas eu acho que a pergunta ficou confusa, no caso seria o contrario eu tenho o valor sem ponto e virgula e quero formatar usando casas decimais.

Comment: @BrunoRichart você precisa disso eu já até tinha respondido: [Formatação com php de numéricos para salvar no banco de dados mysql como DECIMAL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159594/54880)

Answer (score 0):

para virgula use:

```
$numero = '100,30';

$SemVirgula  = str_replace(',', '', $numero );
```

---

para ponto use:

```
$numero = '100.30';

$SemVirgula  = str_replace('.', '', $numero );
```

---

Para ambos use:

```
$numero = '2.100,30';

$SemVirgula  = str_replace(',', '', $numero );

$SemPonto  = str_replace('.', '', $SemVirgula );
```

---

Outra forma para retirar ponto e virgula:

```
$numero = '2.100,30';

$substituir = array(',', '.');

$substituidos = array('', '');

$NumFormatado = str_replace($substituir, $substituidos, $numero);
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, mas eu acho que a pergunta ficou confusa, no caso seria o contrario eu tenho o valor sem ponto e virgula e quero formatar usando casas decimais.